# Informatica ETL: How to determine the target database name from the exported xml file

Tags: informatica

I have an XML file from informatica representing an ETL job. It has source tags for the originators of data and target tags for the destination of data.

The source tags show a DBDNAME attribute (i think this is typically the name of the database) and a NAME attribute (I think this is the table or view name).

```
<SOURCE BUSINESSNAME ="" DATABASETYPE ="Oracle" DBDNAME ="DBA QA" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="GL_LINES" OBJECTVERSION ="1" OWNERNAME ="DBASTA" VERSIONNUMBER ="4">
```

However, the target tags do not have a DBDNAME attribute

```
<TARGET BUSINESSNAME ="" CONSTRAINT ="" DATABASETYPE ="Oracle" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="LT_LOAD_CTL" OBJECTVERSION ="1" TABLEOPTIONS ="" VERSIONNUMBER ="2">
```

How do I determine the destination database name?

Note:
The dtd is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE POWERMART SYSTEM "powrmart.dtd">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... you can't. Informatica uses a `Connection`. This object is defined on `Integration Service` server and contains database sever and name. It is not stored in the `Workflow` XML file.

Edit:
You can use `pmrep` command line utility to get connections and details. Create a batch or run from console the following set of commands:

First, connect to the repository:

```
pmrep connect -r RepositoryName -d DomainName -s SecurityDomain -n UserName -x UserPasswd
```

Once this is successfull, you can fetch all connections:

```
pmrep listconnections > ConnectionList.txt
```

If you need details of any particular connection, run:

```
pmrep getconnectiondetails -n ConnectionName -t ConnectionType
```

Keep in mind that still, in case of ODBC connections, you will get just the `Connections String` name, no server or DB details. It is a good practice to create ODBC with a naming pattern like ServerName_DBName to make this easier - although sometimes just the source name is used.

Make sure to run the cleanup once you're done:

```
pmrep cleanup
```

Comment: Is there another xml file I can export to make the connection between targets and the database?

Answer (score 1):

In xml you can have target database name by filtering tags SESSIONEXTENSION with attribute TRANSFORMATIONTYPE ="Target Definition".

Inside this tag you will have a sub tag CONNECTIONREFERENCE having the realtional connection name with key CONNECTIONNAME if you have used object as a connection type.

If you have used Connection variable as connection type you will have that in key VARIABLE.

Comment: I don't see a TRANSFORMATIONTYPE tag in my xml files. There is a TRANSFORMATION tag. I also see a TRANSFORMATION_TYPE attribute on INSTANCE tags.

Comment: @jshen Sorry for the confusion, I have edited the answer. Tag is SESSIONEXTENSION with attribute TRANSFORMATIONTYPE ="Target Definition".

Answer (score 1):

you can try below Xpath expression to fetch Connection Name for all Target Definition in the workflow XML:

```
/POWERMART/REPOSITORY/FOLDER//SESSION/SESSIONEXTENSION[@TRANSFORMATIONTYPE ="Target Definition"]/CONNECTIONREFERENCE/@CONNECTIONNAME
```

if a connection variable is used, try below:

```
/POWERMART/REPOSITORY/FOLDER//SESSION/SESSIONEXTENSION[@TRANSFORMATIONTYPE ="Target Definition"]/CONNECTIONREFERENCE/@VARIABLE
```

Test the expression by uploading your xml in below url:

https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Comment: As @Maciejg mentioned, you can only fetch the name of the connection if a direct connection is given or the connection variable from the XML.

Comment: This doesn't match anything in my xml file.

Comment: Well Session Extension and COnnection Reference tags will be present if you export the whole workflow. Could you please try it after exporting the whole workflow?